# Get last modified Records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with these values

```
ID, Name  , LastModifedDate
1 , Tom   , 01/01/2014
1 , Romain, 04/01/2014
2 , Paul  , 01/01/2014
3 , John  , 02/01/2014
```

and I need to get latest records like the following

```
1, Romain, 04/01/2014 
2, Paul    01/01/2014
3, John,   02/01/2014
```

Comment: Why should Paul be selected but not Tom?

Comment: @CindyH , looks like he want to get last modified row per ID.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `row_number` to select the last modified row per `ID`

```
select * from (
    select *, 
        row_number() over (partition by ID order by LastModifiedDate desc) rn
    from mytable
) t1 where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    declare @t table (Id int,name varchar(10),lasmodified date)
    insert into @t(Id,name,lasmodified) values (1,'tom','01/01/2014'),
    (1,'Romain','04/01/2014'),(2,'paul','01/01/2014'),(3,'john','02/01/2014')

 ;with  cte as 
    (select ID,name,lasmodified,row_number()OVER(PARTITION BY ID order by lasmodified   desc) RN from @t)

    select ID,name,MAX(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),lasmodified,103)) from cte 
    WHERE RN = 1
    group by ID,name 
order by name desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean all the records since Feb 01?  Why should Paul be selected but not Tom?

```
SELECT ID, Name, LastModifiedDate
FROM YourTable
where LastModifiedDate > '01/01/2014'
```

Or do you want the last three??

```
SELECT TOP 3 ID, Name, LastModifiedDate
FROM YourTable
order by LastModifiedDate desc
```